# Non-compactness of the resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, microlocal-analysis

Consider a complete non-compact Riemannian manifold $M$ and the resolvent of the Laplacian $(-\Delta + \lambda I)^{-1}$. It is known that the resolvent is in general not a compact operator. I am trying to understand why not. I realize that the proof in the compact setting does not follow through for the non-compact case because of the failure of compact Sobolev embedding. I would be happy to see why the resolvent is not compact even for $M = \mathbb{R}^n$, and a justification for general non-compact $M$ would be excellent. Thanks.

Comment: The Laplacian is compact on $\mathbb H/ \Gamma$ for $\Gamma \subseteq \mathop{PSL}_2(\mathbb R)$ a lattice, and this surface need not be compact. See e.g. Bump, _Automorphic forms and representations_ (1998), Theorem 2.3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $M=\mathbb R^n$ take a smooth function with compact support $\phi\in C_0^\infty(M)$.

Then 
$$
\phi = (-\Delta+\lambda I)^{-1}((-\Delta+\lambda I)\phi)
$$
obviously. Now consider translations $\phi_k(x):=\phi(x+kv)$ for $v\in \mathbb R^n$, $k\in \mathbb N$. Take the norm of $v$ large enough such that the supports of different $\phi_k$'s are empty.

The set
$$
X:=\{ (-\Delta+\lambda I)\phi_k,\ k\in\mathbb N\}
$$
is bounded in $L^2$, but
$$
 (-\Delta+\lambda I)^{-1}X
$$
is not relatively compact in $L^2$.

Comment: As far as I can see, your logic goes over to non-compact manifolds as well, right?

Comment: @anonymous: only when you have a "translation" on your manifold (which has to be an isometry to preserve the Laplacian).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to show that for a non-compact manifold the resolvent does not have to be compact is to give a counterexample. Following your (very good) choice of the manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, lets show that $(-\Delta - \lambda I)^{-1}$ is **not compact**. For simplicity, assume $n=2$.

---

Assume $\vec{\mathbf{x}}, \vec{\mathbf{y}} \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then the  fundamental solution $\mathit{\Phi}$  of 2D Laplacian $\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}  \ $  [**takes form**](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~vvksrini/Fund-laplace.pdf)

$$
\mathit{\Phi}\big(\vec{\mathbf{x}}, \vec{\mathbf{y}}\big) =- \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln \big|\vec{\mathbf{x}} - \vec{\mathbf{y}} \big| = 
- \frac{1}{4\pi}\ln \Big( (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 \Big). \label{1}\tag{1}
$$

Recall that the **fundamental solution** of a linear PDE, (which is equivalent to the Green's function) is the kernel of resolvent of the corresponding differential operator.

> For example, see  [this link](http://www.hep.caltech.edu/~fcp/physics/quantumMechanics/resolvent/resolvent.pdf), page 4.

Denote the resolvent $R_\lambda = (-\Delta - \lambda I)^{-1}$. Then the resolvent of 2D Laplacian takes form
$$
R_\lambda[u](\mathbf{x}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \mathit{\Phi}\big(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\big) u (\mathbf{y}).\label{2}\tag{2} $$
Substituting $\eqref{1}$ into $\eqref{2}$, we get

$$
R_\lambda[u](\mathbf{x}) = - \frac{1}{2\pi}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \bigg( \ln \big|\vec{\mathbf{x}} - \vec{\mathbf{y}} \big| \!\cdot\! u (\mathbf{y}) \bigg)\,\mathrm{d}^2 \mathbf y.\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
R_\lambda[u]\big(x_1, x_2\big) =  
- \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \!\bigg(\! \ln\! \Big( (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 \Big)\! \cdot\! u\big(x_1,x_2\big)\! \bigg)dy_1  dy_2, \label{4}\tag{4}
$$
where 
$\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

---

Now, when we have the explicit expression  \eqref{3}, it is easy to see that  the resolvent $R_\lambda$ is not compact, since the integral kernel $\mathit{\Phi}\not\in L^2\big( \mathbb{R}^2\times  \mathbb{R}^2\big) $.

Comment: It seems that you assumed $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: Also, by definition of a resolvent, it has to be bounded.

Comment: @John I took $\lambda = 1$, but occidentally omit this assumption while typing up the answer. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @John Also, what is the definition of resolvent you are talking about? I only know  that resolvent is continuous by definition, and equivalence of boundless and continuity only holds for linear operators. From what I know, in general resolvent of an operator on infinite dimensional domain does not have to be compact.
Moreover, the resolvent of Laplace operator on **bounded** domain with Neumann BCs imposed need not be compact, see Corollary 3.5  page 19  in [http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/chap8.pdf](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/chap8.pdf)

Comment: But now $(\Delta - \lambda I)^{-1}$ is linear. So continuity is the same as boundedness. The definition can be found in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_set . Also in Rudin's functional analysis (p.365)

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry for misleading answer